# Remove duplicates in a json object array

Tags: python, performance

I have a json object of about 6 million items, some of which are duplicates. Currently to remove the duplicates I am doing:

```
clean = []
for item in new:
    if item not in clean: clean.append(item)
```

Unfortunately this is a poor method for this so it takes forever to do. Trying to convert to a `set` also gives me an error since the items in the json object are not nested. What might be a good, fast way to do this?

Example data:

```
new = [
    {'Volume': 'S3', 'LastModified': u'2015-02-04 11:04:59', 'Bucket': 'varx-assets', 'Key': 'Quince/4', 'Size': 0},
    {...}, 
    ...
]
```

Comment: ״gives me an error since the items in the json object are not nested״
it's not clear to me, can you provide an example input of `new` and show the code that uses `set` so that we can repro? (or in other words, provide MCVE)

Comment: May you share a sample of your data?

Comment: @NirAlfasi updated.

Comment: @David542 do you mean that if we have to identical items, they'll still be considered as different because they are different objects?

Comment: Wild idea, load into pandas dataframe and do drop_duplicates

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(new).drop_duplicates().to_dict(orient='records')` something like this?

Comment: @NirAlfasi no, they are literally identical objects. (the code should make that obvious)

Comment: @timgeb ok but in terms of performance?

Comment: @David542 time it :)

Comment: @timgeb two times as fast without pandas (see answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest I could come up with (without using external modules or such) was:

```
>>> t0=time.time();x=[dict(item) for item in {tuple(x.items()) for x in new}]; print time.time()-t0
# 28.6785140038
```

Compared to `pandas`, about twice as fast:

```
>>> t0=time.time();x=pd.DataFrame(new).drop_duplicates().to_dict(orient='records');print time.time()-t0
# 51.7240169048
```